# How do I make a warning only occur once in ruby?

Tags: ruby, warnings

Is it possible to tell ruby to give a warning only once, rather than multiple times?

```
class SoylentGreen
  def eat
    warn "Algae harvesting not implemented. Soylent green is people!"
  end
end

5.times do
  soylent_green = SoylentGreen.new
  soylent_green.eat
end
```

produces

```
Algae harvesting not implemented. Soylent green is people!
Algae harvesting not implemented. Soylent green is people!
Algae harvesting not implemented. Soylent green is people!
Algae harvesting not implemented. Soylent green is people!
Algae harvesting not implemented. Soylent green is people!
```

whereas ideally I'd like it to occur only once.

I'm not using rails, and have access to ruby 1.8 and 1.9.

Alternatives would include writing my own warning system (which'd cover only deliberate warnings like this), or putting the warning outside of `SoylentGreen#eat` (which'd cause it to be displayed even if the method wasn't called).

Answer (score 5):

Based on Chaos's answer..

```
class SoylentGreen
  def eat
    warn_once "Algae harvesting not implemented. Soylent green is people!"
  end
  def warn_once(msg)
    @@warned||=false
    if not @@warned then
       @@warned = true
       warn msg
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The [warnings](https://github.com/postmodern/warnings) gem hides duplicate warnings:

```
require 'warnings'

def danger!
  warn "Fire in the disco!"
end

danger!
danger!

Warnings.grep(/fire/)
# => [...]

Warnings.from('foo/bar.rb')
# => [...]

Warnings.from_method('danger!')
# => [...]

exit
#
# Warnings:
#
#   fire in the disco!
#      lib/foo/bar.rb:42
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like this?
I believe the 2 ampersands make a variable static.

```
class SoylentGreen
  @@warned = false
  def eat
    if not @@warned then
       @@warned = true
       warn "Algae harvesting not implemented. Soylent green is people!"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For the example case, this wouldn't work given that its creating a new instance of the class each loop cycle.

Comment: You could use a class variable if you wanted to go down this path.

Comment: Yeah I had to look that up. I haven't used Ruby.

Comment: @Earlz - Not sure, I certainly don't deserve an up-vote but I definitely don't deserve a down-vote.